# How to create a custom User session object using spring

Tags: spring, session

I build a simple webapp which is part of my learning spring technology.

I was thinking to create some kind of custom user session which holds the reference to a lot of user attributes like for example language , currency might be.

How can i achieve this in spring ? Or there is something already existing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom `authentication provider` and pass a custom `UserDetailsService`

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserService" class="custom.UserServiceImpl">
</beans:bean>

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //Your logic
        return new AuthenticatedUser("", "", true, true, true, new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>());
    }
}

public class AuthenticatedUser extends
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Your additional properties

    public AuthenticatedUser(String username, String password,
            boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, true, authorities);
    }
}
```